# No Option to Manually Start SPD Workflow on a Workflow Task List

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I created a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow attached to a Workflow Task List to Create Items in another list when the workflow task is completed.  I have it set to run Manually, but the Ribbon Action Item for "Workflow" is disabled and also the workflow link in the Items context menu is not shown.  What could I be doing wrong?  This works on other lists.

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is if you published the workflow! (just saving it is not enough).

Comment: Hmm, been there done that, I've actually re-created the Workflow to no avail.  I thought maybe since it is a Workflow Task list that this is not allowed, but that doesn't appear to be the case either.  Also, this was a site upgraded from SP2007 and I've already had to re-create failed workflows due to the upgrade.

Comment: Strange. The only thing I can say is that there are no restrictions specific to Tasks lists.